# AWS Linux: Apache httpd.conf too long to respond

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, xampp

I have this configuration setting on my `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:902>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/e-wallet-frontend/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
Listen 902
```

and my Laravel Project placed in my `/opt/lampp/htdocs/e-wallet-frontend`

I already installed my `composer` and `laravel` on the server all the dependencies are downloaded already.

If I try to navigate the project manually without using `port` something like this

`http://mypublicip/e-wallet-frontend/public/index.php` the project appears but of course lot of errors.

But whenever I try to navigate the project something like this

`http://mypublicip:902/login` since laravel performs the route.

The browser always gives this response, `too long to respond`

This configuration is working on my local. But when I try to use it on `AWS` It doesn't work anymore. Is there anything I need to configure to solve this problem?

UPDATE
using `sudo curl -vv http://mypublicip:902/login`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY1oC.png)

`Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: what logs says? Any reason for using priviliged port?

Comment: As I checked the access_log and error_log It doesn't seems like showing some related logs when I accessed the http:mypublicip:902/login. I tried to restart the lampp using `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` the restart works properly, no error shown

Comment: I don't have domain as of now that's why I need to use port for now for my 2 different project and the port will determine project

Comment: try `curl -vv http://mypublicip:902` and check the output and response. Hope correct security groups and acl's are in place.

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: I'm using curl 7.58.0

Comment: looks like you didn't allow to access 902 port from outside in security group, fix it it should work.

Comment: What is security group by the way? Is that on the configuration of amazon

Comment: You can say it is firewall please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html